# FitNesse - Check if variable does not contain text in script table

Tags: c#, fitnesse, fitnesse-slim

In our FitNesse tests, we use a ScriptTable to call an external tool, which imports some data to our database. The table looks like this:

```
!| script | Fixtures.MyClass |
| Update Dir | c:\FitNesse\XXXX\XXXXX |
| check | Message | |
```

UpdateDir is a function defined in our fixtures. It sets log-content to a variable called "Message". The content of Message looks like this:

```
Daten aus der Tabelle 'Table1' wurden gelöscht.Datei 'c:\FitNesse\XXX\File1.xml' konnte nicht importiert werden: ORA-00904: "ColX": ungültiger Bezeichner
Daten aus der Tabelle 'Table2' wurden gelöscht.Datei 'c:\FitNesse\XXX\File2.xml' wurde erfolgreich importiert.
```

With "check Message" the content of the variable is displayed at Runtime in the table, but not checked so far.

Now i want to extend the table with a row to check the content with a contain function.

If the variable "Message" does not contain the text "ORA-"
Then Success
Else Error

I tried to add the folllowing row to the ScriptTable:

```
| ensure | Message | should not contain | ORA- |
```

But now the table throws an error "ensure Method messageora not found in PassivPlusFixtures.MyClass"
Can somebody help me to achive the desired behavior? Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [check using regular expressions in script tables](http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.WritingAcceptanceTests.SliM.ValueComparisons#RegularExpressionComparisons), using that feature you should be able to do what you need. But given the horrible regular expression, I recommend to hide the check in a scenario.

Something like:

```
|script    |Fixtures.MyClass         |
|Update Dir|c:\FitNesse\XXXX\XXXXX   |
|check     |Message|=~/^((?!ORA).)*$/|
```